# How I fix this attic door misalignment. Hinge bent

Tags: attic, hinges, ladder

[Pictures](https://imgur.com/a/ywMarbm)

Just moved into this home and this attic door does not close. Looks like the hinge (door hinge like part) is bent. How do I fix this? I don't see any parts available either.

I am worried that once I unscrew the screws from the wood. It wouldn't hold the screws tight if I screw them back in. Given that it is a ladder not sure if that's a good idea.

Comment: we do not see what you see, post a picture

Comment: I put a link on top. Is it not showing?

Comment: It is showing ..

Answer (score 1):

Take it all apart. Hammer the bent hinge back in place. Put back together. If the screws won't hold again use the old toothpicks and glue trick or larger diameter screws.

It looks like a pre-built insert. If it's too far gone you may just have to buy a new one to and replace the old one.

Comment: Yep, if the hinge is just too beat up after trying to straighten it, it can easily be replaced with a new continuous hinge for not a lot of money.  And use phillips head screws next time—flatheads are an exercise in frustration here!

Comment: *Slotted*. Flat*head* is the shape... of the head (i.e., *pan*). - I'd wrack on it until it was centered again. Then I'd cut off some of the bottom of the door so that it fits back into its opening. Trying to straighten a piano hinge sounds like a good way to break it. Taking it apart would require two *other* people, lots of swearing, and probably still have to cut some of the door off unless you just buy a new hinge.

Comment: One last try before you toss it: With the legs *not* extended, exert pressure towards the door and slightly in the opposite direction that it wracked in, in the first palace, that made it this way. Which is push away (down), and to the right. Put a moving blanket on the floor for when you happen to pry it out of the ceiling....

Answer (score 0):

Someone use wrong screws and they gave up.

You can safely remove the door (the screws from the hinge.

Get screws that are 50% longer and screw in.

If the screw holes are to big use tooth picks.

Hammer like 3 tooth picks in the hole and cut off to flush.

That should hold the screws.